# Measuring ElasticScheduler with micrometer?

Tags: project-reactor, micrometer, spring-micrometer

Is there any way to measure how `ElasticScheduler` utilities it's thread pools? I've went through code but I haven't seen any straightforward option to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `enableMetrics`on `Schedulers` class.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#enableMetrics--

Comment: (since as of this comment recently released version 3.2.3.RELEASE)